# how to print the list of strings Sorted by the length of each string, shortest strings first..as in following python script?

Tags: python

```
>>>t= ["dddd","a","bb","cccc"]
>>>t.sort(key=lambda s:len(s))
>>>print t
```

output:

```
['a', 'bb', 'dddd', 'cccc']
```

List t is given as input.t gets sorted according to length with 2nd line code.  At last I  print it.
so..now i want to take input,sort the list and print it.. 
      All in one line code(if possible).
I have tried other ways such as..

```
>>> print input().sort(key=lambda s:len(s))
  ["aaa","bb","cccc","q"]  # input
  None                     #output
 - i think it take return value of input(),i.e is None.
```

Comment: Use `sorted` instead of `sort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really not the preferred way to input an array. However, since you are on python 2.x and `input()` evaluates what you put into it, you can simply do:

```
 >>> print sorted(input(), key=len)
 ['aa', 'c', 'bbbb']
 ['c', 'aa', 'bbbb']  # output 
 >>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot input arrays like this. If you want to deal with arrays, create one and then fill it by calling `raw_input()`. Then do sorting.

Answer (score -1):

Just like ForceBru said, you have to use raw_input() to be able to input list. The usual input does not allow you to input pieces of code, instead it's being processed like ordinary string so the result of your input is

```
'["aaa","bb","cccc","q"]'
```

Comment: In python 2.7, it's actually `raw_input()` that treats user input as a string (just as the name dictates). As the python [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input) says, `input()` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`, so `input()` actually **allows** you to input pieces of code.